# Failed to open DWF / DWFX file natively in Forge Viewer

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, forge

I am using the below code to open the DWF file. File size is more than 20MB.

```
const options = {
env: 'Local',
useADP: false}
var config3d = {
    extensions: ['Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore'],
    loaderExtensions: { dwf: "Autodesk.MemoryLimited" },        
};

viewer2D = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv'), config3d);
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options,async function () {
    debugger;
    viewer2D.start();
    viewer2D.setTheme('light-theme');        
    viewer2D.loadExtension('Autodesk.DWF').then(() => {
        viewer2D.loadModel("http://xxxxxx/xxxxx//xxx//xxxx.dwf");
    });

});
```

I am stuck in the Translation. Screenshot below:
[ConsoleError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1WpH.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple Forge application that loads a dwf file on the viewer: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-simple-viewer-nodejs/tree/sample/native-dwf

You can also check out the blog post on Forge support for DWF files: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/dwf-and-pdf-support-forge-viewer

These samples will guide you on how to implement your application.